# Delimit UISwipeGestureRecognizer

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uigesturerecognizer

there is a way to delimit the swipe only on a specific item?

in this way it works everywhere

```
UIGestureRecognizer *recognizer;

//RIGHT
recognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipeRight:)];
self.swipeRightRecognizer =(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)recognizer;
swipeRightRecognizer.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;

[self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeRightRecognizer];
self.swipeRightRecognizer = (UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)recognizer;
[recognizer release];
```

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the swipe recognizer to only the view you want to swipe. Or, you can do this:

```
swipeRightRecognizer.delegate = self;
//...


- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
       shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch {
    return (touch.view == myViewThatShouldReceiveSwipes);
}
```

Comment: thanks but works on everything. You write that I can add the swipe recognizer to only the view I want to swipe, how?

thanks

Comment: Instead of `[self.view addGestureRecognizer:...]` just use `[myViewThatShouldReceiveSwipes addGestureRecognizer:...]`.